# Ошибка при десериализации json

Tags: c#, json

Пытаюсь десериализовать `json` в класс, но выдает ошибку `"Не удается преобразовать объект типа "System.Boolean" в тип "Sell_Offers""` Хочу получить доступ к `offers`

```
var rez = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(json));
```

-

```
{
"success": true,
"results": [
    {
        "classid": "1812818783",
        "instanceid": "188530139",
        "sell_offers": {
            "best_offer": 324,
            "offers": [
                [
                    324,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    444,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    446,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    524,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    528,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    540,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    543,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    554,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    1498,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1500,
                    1
                ]
            ],
            "my_offers": null
        },
        "buy_offers": null,
        "history": null,
        "info": {
            "our_market_instanceid": null,
            "market_name": "P250 | Iron Clad (Немного поношенное)",
            "name": "P250 | Iron Clad",
            "market_hash_name": "P250 | Iron Clad (Minimal Wear)",
            "rarity": "Армейское качество",
            "quality": "Немного поношенное",
            "type": "Пистолет",
            "mtype": "CSGO_Type_Pistol",
            "slot": "Обыч."
        }
    }


]
```

}

Встроенный генератор в Visual Studio дал следующий код класса

```
public class Root
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string classid { get; set; }
    public string instanceid { get; set; }
    public object sell_offers { get; set; }
    public object buy_offers { get; set; }
    public object history { get; set; }
    public Info info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public object our_market_instanceid { get; set; }
    public string market_name { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
    public string rarity { get; set; }
    public string quality { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string mtype { get; set; }
    public string slot { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Вы JSON специально обрезали, или такой неверный у вас и есть?

Comment: пардон, оказывается с ошибкой скопировал.  https://pastebin.com/NXj1eA4K вот полный json

Answer (score 3):

И так, нам надо получить доступ к `offers`. Давайте прогоним через [этот](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu) сайт ваш `JSON`. Что видим?

- У нас есть некий список `results`, в котором каждый объект содержит в себе отдельный объект `sell_offers`.
- Так, смотрим что же в самом `sell_offers`, а в нем у нас нужный нам список `offers`, который состоит из массива с последовательным отображением чисел.

Давайте все это создадим:

```
public class Root
{
    public Result[] results { get; set; } 
}

public class Result
{
    public SellOffers sell_offers { get; set; }
}

public class SellOffers
{
    public List<List<int>> offers { get; set; }
}
```

Я не стал тут выводить другие данные, это уже по аналогии думаю сделаете без проблем. Читать данные можете так же, как и делали. Я кстати советую вам использовать JSON.NET библиотеку, хорошая, удобная.
Вообще я лично не доверяю конвертеру студии, больше нравится [данный](http://json2csharp.com/) сайт, но это уже дело вкусов.

---

Хорошо, раз у нас один объект может быть то `bool`, то список, давайте это проверим. Переделаем `public SellOffers sell_offers { get; set; }` на `public dynamic sell_offers { get; set; }`, от класса `SellOffers` отказываемся и делаем следующее:

```
foreach (var item in rez.results)
{
    var itemType = item.sell_offers.GetType();
    if (itemType.Equals(typeof(bool))) continue; //Пропускаем все те, что имеют тип Bool
    foreach (var offer in item.sell_offers["offers"])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{offer[0]} - {offer[1]}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Написал [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ynPYYj) (правда с JSON.NET, но это всего 1 строка чтения заменяется). Также не стал проходиться по всем `results`, а взял первый.

Comment: на полном json выдает ошибку.

Comment: "Error converting value False to type 'SellOffers'."

Comment: @Zevra Ага, а вот самое главное в примере вы не указали. У вас некоторые sell_offers имеют тип Bool. Вам обязательно стандартными средствами, или можно JSON.NET использовать?

Comment: Стандартными( в этом и загвоздка

Comment: @Zevra Обновил ответ, думаю можно было бы как то привязать `sell_offers` к нужному типу (созданному ранее классу), но что то он не хочет этого делать. Но с проблемой вашей думаю это поможет.